# Array index while iterating DataTables Json Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I have json data looking like the below structure:

```
[
    {"name": "Sitepoint", "url": "http://sitepoint123.com", "editor": {"name": "John Doe", "phone": ["9191919", "1212121"], "email": []}},
    {"name": "Flippa", "url": "http://flippa.com", "editor": {"name": "Adam Smith", "email": ["adam.smith@domain.com"], "phone": []}},
    {"name": "Google", "url": "http://google.com", "editor": {"name": "Google Smith", "email": ["Google.smith@domain.com"], "phone": []}}
]
```

And I am using the dataTables like the following code

```
$("#example").dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost123.com/data_source.json",
    "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "name",
            "sTitle": "Site name"
        }, {
            "mData": "url",
            "mRender": function(url, type, full) {
                return  '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
            }
        }, {
            "mData": "editor.name"
        }, {
            "mData": "editor.phone"
        }, {
            "mData": "editor",
            "mRender": function(data) {
                return data.email.join("");
            }
        }]
});
```

All I want here is Array Index of the Json which it is populating
The above json is "Array with Maps(objects)", 
I want like Array Index of json like

sitepoint is 0,
Flippa is 1,
Google is 2

```
{
    "mData": "url",
    "mRender": function ( url, type, full )  {
    return  '<a href="'+url-ArrayIndex+'?ArrayIndex">' + url + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about IE8, then you can use Array.map (you could use a polyfill for IE8, see link):

indexpos = myArray.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf('SitePoint');

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I probably don't understand the question fully.  To simplify, perhaps you could use the latest version of dataTables 1.10, which integrates this feature natively: http://datatables.net/reference/api/map()

Comment: As I mentioned in the question..I need Json Array index..Please refer the above json example tell me the Index of "sitepoint", "flippa", "Google"... while using that json in datatables I want to use the index.